# To select top 2 values for each unique values in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

the following code delivers an output

CODE:

```
select a.AccountNumber,a.customername,sum (a. AverageBalance) AverageBalance, 
b.Staff_ID,Period, a.Product, b.Branch_Code
from BubbleArchive a, Team b
where a.Bubble_Code= b.Officer_Code and a.year = 2013 and a.Year= b.Year  
and Category = 'toys' 
and (len(Staff_ID)<5 or Staff_ID like '%00') 
group by a.AccountNumber,a.customername, b.Staff_ID,Period,a.Product,b.Branch_Code
order by AverageBalance desc
```

OUTPUT:

```
#AccountNumber  #customername   #AverageBalance #Staff_ID #Period #Caption #Branch_Code #
_________________________________________________________________________________________
#126            #OKOYEO         #78806314       #1059     #1      #Cars    #1           #
#384            #AGWUFEl        #20135548       #5425     #1      #Skate   #1           #
#504            #UCHENDUG       #15730000       #5425     #1      #Xtra    #1           #
#834            #ARINZEE        #10058370       #5425     #2      #Xtra    #1           #
#1068           #EMMANNUElE     #7795364        #5425     #3      #Boat    #1           #
#1099           #UMUDU          #7548387        #5681     #1      #Xtra    #2           #
#1109           #ROKA           #7424560        #5425     #1      #Cars    #1           #
#1202           #AlBERT         #7104167        #5425     #4      #Xtra    #2           #
#2326           #NWANNAHJ       #6779029        #5425     #1      #Xtra    #1           #
#2591           #ROCK           #5000000        #5425     #5      #Boat    #3           #
#2852           #NWOKOCHAC      #4813380        #5425     #6      #Xtra    #1           #
#2948           #ARISAV         #4103225        #5808     #1      #Xtra    #1           #
#3330           #NWAIMOI        #4032209        #1059     #1      #Xtra    #4           #
```

I would like to select top 2 customers for each month (#Period) and each Branch (#Branch_Code) respectively based on their Respective average Balance(#AverageBalance)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

For **SQL SERVER::**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AccountNumber, AverageBalance DESC PARTITION BY Period, Branch_Code) rowNo, * 
      FROM (SELECT a.AccountNumber,a.customername,SUM (a.AverageBalance) AverageBalance, 
                   b.Staff_ID,Period, a.Product, b.Branch_Code
            FROM BubbleArchive a, Team b
            WHERE a.Bubble_Code= b.Officer_Code AND a.year = 2013 AND a.Year= b.Year AND 
                  Category = 'toys' AND (len(Staff_ID)<5 OR Staff_ID LIKE '%00') 
            GROUP BY a.AccountNumber,a.customername, b.Staff_ID,Period,a.Product,b.Branch_Code
            ORDER BY AverageBalance DESC
           ) AS A
     ) AS A 
WHERE rowNo <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Period, Branch_Code ORDER BY AverageBalance DESC ) numofrows, * 
          FROM (SELECT a.AccountNumber,a.customername,SUM (a.AverageBalance) AverageBalance, 
                       b.Staff_ID,Period, a.Product, b.Branch_Code
                FROM BubbleArchive a, Team b
                WHERE a.Bubble_Code= b.Officer_Code AND a.year = 2013 AND a.Year= b.Year  
                      AND Category = 'toys' 
                      AND (len(Staff_ID)<5 OR Staff_ID LIKE '%00') 
                GROUP BY a.AccountNumber,a.customername, b.Staff_ID,Period,a.Product,b.Branch_Code
                ORDER BY AverageBalance DESC
               ) AS Temp
         ) AS Temp
    WHERE numofrows < 3
```